# How to parse file to object in java?

Tags: java, java-17

I want to read data from `file.txt` And then parse it to our object.

For example I have the folllowing  `ferrari.txt` and inside I have

```
Car{mark='ferrari', model='sf90', productionYear=2020, hp=1000}
```

now I should parse this to the `Car` Object.

But all over what I could find on google is not looking like what I should use  (maybe I search wrong)

Adding the code :
Main:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car car1 = new Car("ferrari", "sf90", 2020, 1000);
        Car car2 = new Car("fiat", "panda", 2015, 95);
        Car car3 = new Car("bmw", "m5CS", 2018, 645);
        Car car4 = new Car("audi", "rs7", 2019, 750);
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(car1, car2, car3, car4));
        createCarFile(carList); //method to create the file (not added in the code)
        write(carList); //method to wride the file (not added in the code)

        readFileByMark("ferrari");
}
 public static void readFileByMark(String mark) {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mark + ".txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I am reading the file name  I want to call in the method -   Now I assume that insde this code I have to do the "parse" ?

Comment: You can't "parse" that, you'll have to map it. read all the data in there, call the constructor of the Car class, and, if need be, use some setters to finish it off

Comment: You can't just parse it to an object. Either read the file and for each line use the setters and getters of your object to set the data or map the data to an appropriate data structure before you set any object fields.

Comment: @Stultuske is there any chance that you can please give to me an example ? 
Code has been added above

Comment: @BirsanVictor everything you need is already in that code. Just read the text line by line, use substring and indexof of the String class, and extract the correct data, in order to pass it to a constructor

Comment: @Stultuske , can you please give me anhend and show me an example  please?

Comment: what do you need that you don't already have yet? Just check the documentation for the String class for substring and indexof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "parse" that format. You could do that if you serialized the `Car` Object in a binary file. But since you are using a plain text file, something like this would not be possible. The format is also not a well-known one (such as JSON). If it were one of the well-known formats, you could use one of the many available libraries out there to do it for you. You could try to map the fields, but that is not that straightforward.

My suggestion is to change the format to [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). It is human understandable, quick to work with and there is a variety of libraries supporting it.